# Getting next state from ionicView.beforeLeave

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I know that there is `$stateChangeStart` function in angular that can perform action as follow.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

});
```

However, i am developing an ionic v1 app, in which i would like to use a more intuitive way, which is the ionic life cycle. I am wondering if it is possible to get `toState` and `toParams` in `$ionicView.beforeLeave` as i am unable to find any documentation on this. eg:

```
$rootScope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function (event, toState, toParams) {

});
```

Comment: @yehiaasalam  
what exactly you mean by the next state ? , you probably goign to a dynamic page ?

Comment: @Webruster the next view I mean. It's dynamic, however I would like to set the a root variable depending the next view.

Answer (score 1):

The ionic $ionicView.beforeLeave event can take function with 2 arguments. From the argument you can get only from state, it will not give you to state.

```
    $rootScope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function(event, data){
   // handle event
        console.log("Event: ", event); 
        console.log("Data: ", data);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had to use the global state listener, and hardcode the views like below:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        var states_hidetab = [  'app.shoppingcart', 
                                'app.home-product', 
                                'app.payment', 
                                'app.shipping', 
                                'app.review-order', 
                                'app.points'
                            ];

        $rootScope.hideTabs = states_hidetab.includes(toState.name);

    });
```